# Cannot start Stack Dump

Tags: python, stack-dump

When I'm try to launch the start_web.sh script of Stack Dump, I've got this kind of error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/stephan/Schreibtisch/Stack Exchange/stackdump/python/packages/bottle.py", line 744, in _handle
return route.call(**args)
File "/home/stephan/Schreibtisch/Stack Exchange/stackdump/python/packages/bottle.py", line 1479, in wrapper
rv = callback(*a, **ka)
File "./python/src/stackdump/app.py", line 152, in wrapped
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "./python/src/stackdump/app.py", line 175, in wrapped
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "./python/src/stackdump/app.py", line 199, in wrapped
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "./python/src/stackdump/app.py", line 292, in index
context['random_questions'] = get_random_questions(count=settings.NUM_OF_RANDOM_QUESTIONS)
File "./python/src/stackdump/app.py", line 736, in get_random_questions
results = solr_conn().search(query, rows=count, sort=random_field_name)
File "/home/stephan/Schreibtisch/Stack Exchange/stackdump/python/packages/pysolr.py", line 618, in search
response = self._select(params)
File "/home/stephan/Schreibtisch/Stack Exchange/stackdump/python/packages/pysolr.py", line 345, in _select
return self._send_request('get', path)
File "/home/stephan/Schreibtisch/Stack Exchange/stackdump/python/packages/pysolr.py", line 323, in _send_request
raise SolrError(error_message % params)
SolrError: Failed to connect to server at 'http://localhost:8983/solr/stackdump/select/?q=%2A%3A%2A&sort=random_9101+desc&rows=3&wt=json', are you sure that URL is correct? Checking it in a browser might help: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8983): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/stackdump/select/?q=%2A%3A%2A&sort=random_9101+desc&rows=3&wt=json (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Have a nice Day!

Comment: You are connecting to `localhost` - is that right?

Comment: Yes, the service should be running on port 8080

Comment: But your error says it tried to connect to `port=8983`.

Comment: How can I change this?

Comment: I don't know and don't know your file `start_web.sh`. Try figuring out, how the `url` is created you want to use / open.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ./star_solr.sh first, since it's the underlying indexation engine that will allow stackdump to work. Be aware that you need to import a site before you have anything avalaible in stackdump.